# If I lack a certain localization in iTunesConnect, what determines which keywords are used?

Tags: ios, localization, app-store, search-engine, app-store-connect

Lately I have been trying many different keywords in an attempt to find a good search niche for a new game project I've taken on. Running out of ideas, I've started trying seriously random words. Occasionally I forget to update all of the localizations at once, and only update the UK English localization, and this has led to odd behavior.

Currently, I do not have an "English" localization for this game, but I do have a UK English localization which is set at the "Default". However, the UK English localization's keywords are not being used in the US app store, even though the UK English localization's description is used.

I can tell because I tried a few keywords completely unrelated to my app, words not used in my description, or app title, and completely unrelated to my game but when I changed the UK Localization to remove them about a week later, I forgot to change the many other localizations. The other localizations include French, German, Italian, Japanese, Korean, Russian, Simplified Chinese, Spanish, Thai and Traditional Chinese.

This leads me to believe that the keywords and descriptions of localizations are handled very differently by the app store search engine.

I can think of three possibilities for when you lack a certain localization:

• Keywords from all localizations are used for the store that doesn't have a localization. (This doesn't seem likely, I don't rank for "的朋友" for example even though it is a keyword in my Chinese localization)

• Keyword list is chosen at random from available localization (Also doesn't seem programmatically likely)

• Keyword list is chosen from first list in alphabetically sorted localizations list (Possible, as French is the first localization alphabetically and did still hold these unrelated keywords)

Has anyone seen similar behavior, or could maybe shed some light on what's going on here?

Comment: I always thought that it was as this: the default language was always used and the local language too. So if you are in the US and your default language is English UK, then both your US English keywords + your UK keywords would work there. If you were in China, then you'd have UK + Chinese. I read about this, but don't have the source at hand.

Comment: you can use services like app annie or sensor tower